# plotly and ggplotly: hiding and unhiding parts of a graph

Tags: r, ggplotly

The following code creates a graph in which clicking on the legend labels adds or removes color from single curves. Is there a way to configure which curves are colored and which not?
I need this for a chart with ~ 20 curves and I want only one to be colored initially.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

my_data <-
  tibble(x=seq(0,1,0.05),
             y2=x^2,
             y3=x^3)
my_data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols=y2:y3,
    names_to="fun",
    values_to="value"
  ) -> my_data_long

my_data_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value,group=fun)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_path(aes(color=fun)) -> gg

ggplotly(gg)
```